# Hard Drive Corrupted

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

[image]I Erased my hard drive from mac utilities from the recovery mode, but now i am not able to install Mac OS Mojave as it doesn't shows my mac hard drive to install and when i checked it in utilities, it shows the drive as UN-formatted[image]. So now i cannot install mac os and my ssd has been erased. What can i do for it ? 
I am attaching a image that it is showing in the disk utilities.

Comment: **Please answer the question**: Did you want to erase your SSD hard drive? Or do you want to recover your erased partition? You need to explain this, because if you format your SSD hard drive, you may never be able to recover your erased data.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to erase my SSD, I wanted to reset my MAC , but at first when i erased the drive it was showing the drive , but now it is showing it as unformatted and i cannot install the OS in that drive.

Comment: What is your current version of macOS?

Comment: I had OS Mojave before.

Comment: And i am ok with my ssd erased as i wanted to install a new fresh copy of macOS

Comment: Can you take a better picture of the whole screen? I'm not an expert on this, but you should be able to use Disk Utility to format the unformatted partition.

Comment: the option to erase the disk is blurred, i cannot click it, I tried to do first aid of the drive, but still the error persists.

Comment: the answer below is an attempt to erase your disk from the command line as the GUI does not appear to be giving you the option. Is the disk you are working on the internal disk? If yes, then continue. Do you have any other disks attached? If yes, disconnect the external disks then continue. After booting to recovery mode 1. pull up a terminal by selecting terminal from the utilities menu 2. In the terminal type 'diskutil list | grep internal'. The output should be something like '**/dev/disk0** (internal)'. Note the path (in bold). 3. type the following: 'diskutil erasedisk APFS **MacOS** GPT

Comment: It says could'nt unmount disk. after i enter the second command.

Comment: i used diskutil unmountdisk force /dev/disk0 , but it shows - 'Forced unmount of disk0 failed : at least one volume could not be unmounted. '

Comment: Yes, this is because we are trying to erase the disk whilst we are using it (you are currently booting from the Recovery OS which is a volume on the disk we are trying to erase). I am sorry that that didn't occur to me before. If you really need to wipe the disk clean you will need to do it from an installer or by booting from another disk with macOS on it. I am looking into other alternatives.

Comment: from your picture you appear to be in the partition submenu and currently targeting the unformatted part. Go back in to diskutil and get the unformatted part highlighted (as in your picture).  Is the + sign active (not greyed out)? If so, click it and you will have the option of entering new partition information (Name, format [choose APFS] and size [make sure it is at least 30GB]). then click apply and follow through. If that works then that partition will become available for installing to. If that works we can free up the remaining partitions after and get back the space.

Comment: no the + sign is greyed out, I have tried that.

Comment: Can I create a usb bootable stick having macOS using my Windows ?

Comment: apparently, yes. here is a guide to doing that: https://pureinfotech.com/create-macos-bootable-usb-windows/

Comment: thanks man, I will let you know if it goes right,

Comment: but before you do that (or whilst you are doing that) could you do a 'diskutil list' command and paste the output here?

Comment: and by the way, the reason the + is greyed out is that this tool does not allow you to partition free space (as was pointed out to me here recently). The other option is to resize the existing container to reclaim the disk space but first, i am getting you to do what i should have asked for at the start ('diskutil list').

Comment: I added the pic of diskutil list.

Comment: Can you try the following command?     'diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s3 0'

Comment: it is saying that - disk0s3 is not an APFS Physical Store

Comment: indeed, it isn't, please try 'diskutil apfs convert disk0s3'

Comment: apfs couldn't recognise verb 'convert'

Comment: was that the exact error message if not, could you please post it?

Comment: diskutil: did not recognise APFS verb "convert"; type "diskutil apfs" for a list

Comment: i see. apparently diskutil in earlier versions of macOS had some functionality stripped out and we were supposed to use  a different command. please try   'apfs_hfs_convert -v -i /dev/disk0s3'.

Comment: its is saying Conversion Failed! /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/apfs_executables/apfs-249.20.2/hfs/hfs_convert.c:4265 slice=-1 phase=1 location=81 error=-4

Comment: Given the volume of back and forth, it's not clear an edit will make this clear. Please do flag for reopening if you can make a good edit to this or the linked answer doesn't help you move forward. By including your research and showing which steps you took - sometimes that shows how a question isn't a duplicate of another.